# npm installation and npm dev for laravel not working

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

Good day everybody,

[Please I am **NOT** dumping code/error here I am not sure what information may be required by anyone who wants to help, which the reason why I have to provide all information which I believe may be important/neccessary and also I do not know where else I can put the detailed information in]

After installing laravel it was showing the error in the webpage that app.css, app.js were not found

Then I ran the command

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

This gave me the result

```
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1094 packages from 506 contributors and audited 1097 packages in 917.337s
found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> @ dev C:\laravel_directory
> npm run development


> @ development C:\laravel_directory
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
      throw err;
      ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Assert.js:13:9)
    at JavaScript.register (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\JavaScript.js:40:16)
    at Api.mix.(anonymous function).args [as vue] (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentFactory.js:98:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laravel_directory\webpack.mix.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at yargs.parse (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
    at C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laravel_directory\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T03_38_32_222Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T03_38_32_412Z-debug.log
```

Please what am I supposed to do to be able to have the installation working as it is supposed to.

Comment: Please include the webpack.mix.js here

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI The webpack.mix.js came with the installation I did not make any modification to it

Answer (score 3):

I've faced same error on laravel 8 when installing vue on it.

It's actually adding content in webpack.mix.js file like vue().

replace vue() to the following:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

then run `npm run watch`

Comment: Thank you, please can you shed more light on this. I do not know which of the files I would be making changes to. Please can you make it more clear. Thank you

Comment: @SMev, if you are using laravel 8, just open command line in your root directory and type 

npm i laravel-mix@next

It will update laravel mix version 5 to version 6 which support vue version 3.

but if you don't want to do the above then 

navigate to the root directory of your project and open 'webpack.mix.js'.

then you find code "vue()"

replace it with 

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Comment: actually in laravel 8, it adds "vue()" code in 'webpack.mix.js' but when you run 'npm run watch' it through error that vue() function has no parameter. Its happening due to not updating the larvel-mix so it can be compatible to vue 3

I hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

Delete your node_module folder and then again run the command.